# JPQL ManyToMany Query Issue

Tags: hibernate, orm, jpa, jpql, hibernate-mapping

My Entity mapping is as follows:

```
public class EntertainmentContentBean implements Serializable, Cloneable {
.
.
.
@ManyToMany
    @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL)
    @JoinTable(schema = "etmt", name = "content_operator", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "content_id"), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "operator_id"))
    public Set<Operator> getOperators() {
        return operators;
    }
.
.
.

}
```

I've a specific requirement where I want to retrieve EntertainmentContentBean records based on following criteria:

- If no operator records are present
- If operator records are present, then operator list should contain the operator object passed are the parameter

I tried following query but it is not returning expected records:

```
SELECT NEW MAP (content AS content, id AS record_id)
        FROM EntertainmentContentBean contentEntry
        WHERE (contentEntry.operators is empty or (select op from Operator op where lower(op.key) = lower(:operator)) MEMBER OF contentEntry.operators))
```

Comment: What excactly is wrong? Which records are returned?

Comment: The records are an cartesian join with contentEntry.operators table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using subquery to get the desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly is wrong with this query, but I would suggest you to rewrite it in a simplier form, perhaps it would help:

```
SELECT DISTINCT NEW MAP (ce.content AS content, ce.id AS record_id)
FROM EntertainmentContentBean ce LEFT JOIN ce.operators op
WHERE op IS NULL OR lower(op.key) = lower(:operator)
```

Comment: Hi.. it surely simplifies the query but the result is still the same... :(